# Fill ComboBox DataSource from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, casting, combobox, datatable

When using the following code on a field that returns a string it works perfect, but when the field is of type long or Double I get errors :

1. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.
2. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.

respectively.

```
string f = cb.Name.Substring(2, cb.Name.Length - 2);
cb.DataSource = SQLite.GetValues(f).AsEnumerable()
    .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<string>(f))
    .ToArray();
```

in the above SQLite.GetValues returns a datatable. That I am trying to use as the datasource for the combobox.

Is there any small changes I can make to this one Linq statement to make it work?

when I change the line of code `.Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<string>(f))` to `.Select<System.Data.DataRow, Int64>(x => x.Field<Int64>(f))` or `.Select<System.Data.DataRow, Double>(x => x.Field<Double>(f))` it then works for those fields but not the others.

Short of using an if statement to first check the field then running the appropriate line of code is there any other way around this?

the method `GetValues` is also used to populate the DataSource of a DataGridView that will have all columns that is why I do not just return a List or Array from `GetValues`

Also considered is simply do a loop on the DataRows of the DataTable returned to fill the ComboBox perhaps this is best?

For example:

```
string f = cb.Name.Substring(2, cb.Name.Length - 2);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = SQLite.GetValues(f,false);
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    cb.Items.Add(dr[f]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cast your field in string, use the method .ToString().

Comment: When I try `x.Field<string>(f.ToString())` OR `x.Field<string>(f).ToString()` I get the same `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.`error if I try  to not include `<string>` cast it won't compile.